# Google play shows error code 504 for Android N preview

Tags: android, google-play

I developed an app and published it on the `Play store`, but some users experienced problem with install from store. `They get an error code 504 during installation.` The problem occurs only on `Android N` devices. Does anybody has same issue?

UPDATE:

After install `Android N` device gives me this log error:

```
-24 20:29:32.941 4736-6127/? E/PackageInstaller: Commit of session  1647022075 failed: Failed to collect certificates from    /data/app/vmdl1647022075.tmp/com.xxx: META-INF/CERT.SF indicates /data/app/vmdl1647022075.tmp/com.xxx is signed using APK Signature Scheme v2, but no such signature was found. Signature stripped?
06-24 20:29:32.946 24718-24718/? E/Finsky: [1] com.google.android.finsky.installer.ac.onReceive(2624): Error -504 while installing com.xxx: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES: Failed to collect certificates from /data/app/vmdl1647022075.tmp/com.xxx: META-INF/CERT.SF indicates /data/app/vmdl1647022075.tmp/com.xxx is signed using APK Signature Scheme v2,
```

but no such signature was found. Signature stripped?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android N introduces APK Signature Scheme v2 and Android Studio 2.2 use it by default. If you have build problem as I do just add

```
v2SigningEnabled false
```

in the build.gradle app level file.

You can find more [here](https://developer.android.com/preview/api-overview.html#apk_signature_v2)

Comment: Results in Error:Gradle DSL method not found: 'v2SigningEnabled()'

Answer (score 2):

Add this to the app-level build.gradle:

```
android {
    signingConfigs {
        defaultConfig{
            v2SigningEnabled false
        }
    }
}
```

"defaultConfig" is the default product flavor. If you have other flavors, you should add them likewise:

```
android {
    signingConfigs {
        flavor1{
            v2SigningEnabled false
        }
        flavor2{
            v2SigningEnabled false
        }
    }
}
```

Not sure what flavors you have? You can discover them in Android Studio by clicking Build > Edit Flavors.They will be listed in the middle column.